# How do the flag limits work?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I know there are limits on the number of flags one can cast in a day. I found this in the FAQ:

> **How many flags do I have?**
>
> When you start out you are alloted 10 flags per-day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per-day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.

However, I have only 7 offensive flags remaining and I haven't flagged anything yet today. I have 12 flags moderator attention flags left also. (I suppose I've already gained a few additional bonus flags)

What are the original flag limits for each type of flag per day? How many must I flag to receive additional bonus flags?

Comment: Are you really lacking in flags? Are you hitting your limit in flags per day? There must be a lot of offensive crap out there everyday.

Comment: No, this is just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I asked [How is the number of flags for moderation attention calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131207/how-is-the-number-of-flags-for-moderation-attention-calculated) the given answer said:

- default 10 per day
- one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
- one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default
- maximum 100

The flag weight is not anymore visible in the user profiles; the third point needs to be translated in terms of useful flags. Basing on [this answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80178/140449) (visible to MSO's 10K users), *20 "flag weight"* would mean 2 useful flags. Basing on that answer, the increment is for any flag.

> For every 20 points of flag weight beyond the default, you get one additional moderator, comment, and spam/offensive flag per day.

Comment: How are the flags split between *spam/offensive* and *inform moderator* flags?

Comment: There are different counters.

Comment: So, do offensive flags work the same as the other type, except they start with five (or some nearby number)?

Comment: That, or the number of useful flags is kept separated. I have 51 flags for moderation attention, and 46 flags for spam posts; that could be explained in two different ways.